# Visual Svn: mehod to show log of child folder without offline issue

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

i searched couple of question and answer, and I found some kind of solutions which is

1. add below in authz file,

   ```
   [/]
   * = r
   @User = rw
   $anonymous = r
   ```
2. in svnserve.conf,

   ```
   anon-access = none
   auth-access = write
   ```

but then I still have problem with show log of the child folder.
(don't have problem showing parent folder.)

is ther any other solution for showing off of child folder?
thanks.

Comment: FYI: `@user` is not a user, it is a group account.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand what exactly you are trying to do. But you should not manually modify the contents of authz files. Moreover, VisualSVN Server does not even use `svnserve`.

You should use the VisualSVN Server Manager console or [PowerShell](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/powershell/) to manage the access rules. If you have questions about the user permissions in VisualSVN Server and Subversion, read the article [KB33: Understanding VisualSVN Server authorization](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00033/).

Read the [VisualSVN Server Getting Started](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/getting-started/) guide and the section [Configuring User Permissions](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/getting-started/#User-Permissions) in particular.